# GoogleMap v2 crash if first use Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I added a GoogleMap v2 in my Android application. In normal use, I don't have problem. 
However, if I reset my phone and install my app, the map crash.

**report :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
```

When I update google services, this bug disappears.

anyone would have a track, or a way to force the user to update the Google services before use  app ?

Thanks

**Exception :**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.app/com.test.app.activity.AcHome}: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.s.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.aX(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.app.activity.AcHome.onCreate(AcHome.java:126)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your all logcat.

Comment: You can have a look at my helper library on github: https://github.com/yayaa/MapHelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check before launching your maps activity if the user has an updated version of Google Play Services, or at least the one you need.

> `public static int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context context)`
>
> Verifies that Google Play services is installed and enabled on this
>   device, and that the version installed on this device is no older than
>   the one required by this client.
>
> Returns status code indicating whether there was an error. Can be one
>   of following in ConnectionResult: SUCCESS, SERVICE_MISSING,
>   **SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED**, SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID,
>   DATE_INVALID.

If you do this 'check' and receive 'update_required' then you can redirect the user to that update.

Check the link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)

Is this what you are looking for?